# WPF Toolkit and Publishing WPF application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, publish, wpftoolkit

I am having problems publishing a WPF application that references WPFToolkit library.  When I publish the app using ClickOnce using Visual Studio 2010 Express and run the app on a remote machine, it is giving errors "Cannot start application".  Works fine on my development environment though.  When I remove the reference to WPFToolkit in my project, it can run on the remote machine but my project needs that library to run.  Any suggestions? Thanks.

**SOLUTION FOUND**

```
<Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\server\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WpfApplicationTest\WpfApplication\images\cool-light-background-vector_edit.jpg" Stretch="Fill" /> 
</Grid.Background>

**SHOULD BE**
<Grid.Background>
<ImageBrush ImageSource="images\cool-light-background-vector_edit.jpg" Stretch="Fill" /> 
</Grid.Background>
```

**EDITED** Error in log

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\Jewellery\WpfApplication.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Value does not fall within the expected range.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [16/12/2014 18:14:47] : Activation of C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\Jewellery\WpfApplication.application has started.
    * [16/12/2014 18:14:48] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [16/12/2014 18:14:48] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [16/12/2014 18:14:48] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [16/12/2014 18:14:50] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [16/12/2014 18:14:51] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A, processorArchitecture=msil using Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [16/12/2014 18:14:51] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A, processorArchitecture=msil using Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [16/12/2014 18:14:51] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.
    * [16/12/2014 18:15:00] : Downloading of subscription dependencies is complete.
    * [16/12/2014 18:15:00] : Commit of the downloaded application has started.
    * [16/12/2014 18:15:06] : Installation of application has successfully completed.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [16/12/2014 18:15:06] System.ArgumentException
        - Value does not fall within the expected range.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation)

Comment: Did you take care of .NET version dependency?

Comment: Find the error in event viewer, that is more useful than "Cannot start application".

Comment: did you check to include the WPFToolkit dlls are set to Include in your project's properties->Publish->Application Files?

Comment: Thanks guys, I did include all the dll present in Toolkit to be on safeside and just modified the initial post to show the initial part of the error

Comment: Guys, error was in my application where I was referencing images through the complete path as shown above!!